# no such a file or directory

Tags: c, ubuntu, systypes.h

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and trying to run prog1.c as follow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<usr/include/sys/types.h>

int main()
{
printf("Hello World");
}
```

---

```
$gcc prog1.c
```

and gets the error "fatal error: /usr/include/sys/types.h :no such a file or directory"

Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second #include line. You aren't using any declarations from sys/types.h.

If you do want to start using them, the correct way to add the include would be:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
```

Comment: indeed, having the compiler sort it out is more portable than hardcoding it